# Will change in job title cause a problem in getting TN visa?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, united-states, legal, visa

I'm Canadian, working now in the US on TN visa. Position title is Tech Lead, but in the Support Letter, it was written that I would perform responsibilities of a Computer System Analyst, so I got the TN without problem.

I now got a new offer, but the position title is C# .Net Developer. Will this cause a problem in getting TN? Maybe a correct Support Letter can fix it?

**Notes**:

- About TN, [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TN_status):

  > TN status or TN visa is a special non-immigrant status in the United States, Canada, and Mexico that offers expedited work authorization to a citizen of these countries.
- Computer System Analyst is in [NAFTA job list](https://tnvisaexpert.com/overview/nafta-job-list/), but Developer is not.
- Please also see this article: [TN Visa Approval: Software Engineer; prior denial as Programmer](https://www.tnvisabulletin.com/nafta-tn-blog/2010/2/10/tn-visa-approval-software-engineer-prior-denial-as-programme.html)

Comment: The OP is concern that now he is a developer that he will be denied with his TN Visa once he renews. The reason mainly is because under the TN NAFTA law, it's specific to only Computer Systems Analyst and not 'Developers'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you will need to do when you renew your TN visa at the border is to present a new offer letter with the Developer title with developer responsibilities. What the TN reviewer is looking for is to make sure your responsibilities matches your University/College degree. As long as your degree matches your new position, you'll get approved. In your case, it's not much of a stretch.

TN Immigration actually does not list every job combination and possibilities for all applicable fields. All CIS/IT jobs gets bundled up as "Computer Systems Analyst" IE: Quality Assurance Engineer, C#/Java/.Net Developer, Project Managers, IT Director, SQL Developer, Business Analyst, Systems Analyst, etc.

The only way you'll get denied is if you have a CS degree that does not match your new role. IE: You are nurse working in a Hospital for BlueCross. AND OR your offer letter is messed up and missing critical information.

Sources: I worked in the US with a TN visa from 2006 - 2010 until I got my green card and no longer needed it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2Pzr-NK6E0

Comment: problem that Developer isn't in NAFTA list, but CSA is. https://www.tnvisabulletin.com/nafta-tn-blog/2010/2/10/tn-visa-approval-software-engineer-prior-denial-as-programme.html

Comment: That's OK @Alexan. CSA composes of all the jobs under Computer Science not just Analyst. I was Quality Assurance, Business Analyst to SQL Developer and all are under CSA. There are tons of developers working in the US through a TN Visa. How do you think they got approved? The most important is your degree and your responsibilities correlating to that degree.

Comment: I did not have a degree, but I was able to get a TN visa for a software development job by describing it as falling under the "scientific technician" category, as coached by company lawyers, emphasizing that I wouldn't be working independently but would be under the supervision of a fully-credentials engineer (i.e. my tech lead). I was initially rejected for pre-approval, but eventually got through, albeit with some skeptical looks from immigration officers. But I wouldn't have been able to do it without the lawyer's advice...

Comment: You will have to get those same assurances from your new employer I would imagine.  Odd you accepted this answer when it seems it does not actually answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound  Outside of providing an offer letter detailing his responsibilities, position, benefits and salary, his employer does not have any other responsibilities. This is all done in the border with the TN immigration where you get interviewed and you as an employee have to show proof of your transcripts and degree. I've done this so many times through Tijuana Mexico and Toronto, CA border and every question is the same. What the company, what's your position, where do you live, what school you went to, show me your transcripts + degree. Pay the fee. TN visa stamp.